# Use function for all selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, selected

I ran into some problems with using a JavaScript function for all selected checkboxes. Here's how it looks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(source) {
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox');
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
    function backToActive(id){     // for a single item
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/backtoactive/'+id,
            success: function(){
                $("#line_"+id).hide(1000);  
            }
        });
    }
    function massiveBackToActive(){    // for multiple checked items
        var pids = checkedProducts.join();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { ids : pids },
            url: '/massivebacktoactive/',
            success: function(){
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }
        });
    }
    function checkProduct(id){
        var a = checkedProducts.indexOf(id);
        if( a >= 0 ){
            checkedProducts.splice(a,1);
        }
        else{
            checkedProducts.push(id);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then I have this:

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" />
    </th>
    <th>img</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr id="line_<?php echo $item->productid;?>">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onchange="checkProduct(<?php echo $item->productid;?>)" />
    </td>
    <td><a href="/item/?id=<?php echo $item->productid;?>" class="bold"><img src="<?php echo $item->imgurl;?>" /></a></td>
    <td><a target="_new" href="<?php echo $item->url;?>" class="bold"><?php echo $item->name;?></a></td>
</tr>
```

Now, the problem I have is that if I select multiple items 1 by 1, everything works great. However, if I select them all with the `selectall` checkbox, the function doesn't work any more. I mean, it's not applied to the selected items.

The strange thing is that if I select them all and then deselect some of them, the function is applied to the unchecked items. It acts as if it tracks the clicks, but I am using `onChange`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is changing the checked property value programatically won't fire the change event so when you use the check all, `checkedProducts` array won't get updated.

But since you are using jQuery try a complete jQuery solution, so change your markup like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxall" />
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" data-id="<?php echo $item->productid;?>" />
```

then

```
$('#checkboxall').change(function () {
    $('input[name="checkbox"]')[this.checked ? 'not' : 'filter'](':checked').prop('checked', this.checked).change();
})

$('input[name="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id')
    if (this.checked) {
        checkedProducts.push(id);
    } else {
        var index = checkedProducts.indexOf(id);
        if (index > -1) {
            checkedProducts.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    console.log(checkedProducts)
})

function backToActive(id) { // for a single item
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/backtoactive/' + id,
        success: function () {
            $("#line_" + id).hide(1000);
        }
    });
}

function massiveBackToActive() { // for multiple checked items
    var pids = checkedProducts.join();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            ids: pids
        },
        url: '/massivebacktoactive/',
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your response, but sadly, this doesn't solve it. In fact, it doesn't even work selecting all items. If you have any other suggestions, I will be very happy to try them.

Comment: @Jocker there were some syntax errors.... fixed them.... try now - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7s7Lomkp/1/

Comment: No... Sorry, but it still doesn't work... I can see in fiddle that it's working, but for some reason, it's not working my code. And I am absolutely sure I didn't make any mistakes. With the function toggle() that I was using before, the toggling of the checkboxes was working.

Comment: @Jocker whether the checkboxes are created dynamically after the page is loaded

Comment: That was absolutely perfect, man! Thank you very very much.
Since this is my first question here, I don't really know how this works, so if there's any way for me to give you some feedback or something like that, let me know please.

Comment: @Jocker As I said in the answer... when toggle is called, you are programatically changing the checked property which does not trigger the change event so for those elements `checkProduct` won't get called... so in the solution we are changing the checked proprty and is triggering the `change` event manually so that the handlers will get executed